# Mouse cursor on kivy is hidden when .py runs as startup on RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new in Kivy and this question might be silly, but I need to fix this issue.

I have a Kivy app running on raspberry pi stretch lite. I set config.ini for Kivy mouse and it is working as long as it runs by:

```
python KivyTest.py
```

But if I set the file on startup mode doing this:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

...then write:

```
sudo python //KivyTest.py &
```

...before the exit 0

then after rebooting, py runs automatically but on this mode, the mouse is hidden and I can not see it. while it has an effect on buttons on Kivy app when I click it.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

side to side comparison

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing your application at startup in "/etc/rc.local" with "sudo" which means as a root-user, you need to make the same modifications to the "config.ini" file for showing the cursor in the following path:

`/root/.kivy/config.ini`

as you did for "config.ini" in:

`~/.kivy/config.ini`

P.S. The tilde (~) symbol stands for your home directory.